# libxml2.parseFile for online files?

Tags: python, libxml2

I'm trying to search around with XPath on Python, using `libxml2.parseFile`. For some reason, I'm unable to use this function with online files: any ideas on how to quickly solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "unable"? You get an error?

Comment: i'm getting `parserError: xmlParseFile() failed` , i'm starting to think it's because the file is not a .xml file, but just a webpage, thought it would work with it ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using [lxml](http://lxml.de/), a *"Pythonic binding for the C libraries libxml2 and libxslt"*:

```
from lxml.html import parse
import urllib

SOURCE = 'http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered'

htmlpage = urllib.urlopen(SOURCE)
tree = parse(htmlpage).getroot()

print (tree.xpath('//div[1]'))

htmlpage.close()
```

Comment: why did you `import parse` and not `import etree` (seems to be what i keep finding online)?

Comment: ElementTree (`etree`) is a different API. Here I am importing the HTML parser because it will handle also invalid markup, which is quite common on the web. A XML parser would reject it. BTW, the module is `lxml.html`, `parse` is the function I am importing from the module.

Comment: If your files are valid XML, you can use `etree` too. What changes is the parsing strategy, they both have a `xpath` method.